# access to the xml properties from xmlparser

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML that I parse with

```
$response = new SimpleXMLElement($output);
```

It returns the following:

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [meta] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [status] => ok [statuscode] => 100 [message] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [data] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )

I tried to return the statuscode (100) with many variation of this:

```
$response->$meta[0]['statuscode'];
```

or this

```
$response->$meta[0]->statuscode;
```

but I don't find the right syntax to return the value. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no variable `$meta` in the example code.

As there is a single SimpleXmlElement, you could use the statuscode property.

```
$statusCode = (string)$response->meta->statuscode;
```

If there are more elements, you might use the index 0 to get the first one.

```
$response = new SimpleXMLElement($output);
$statusCode = (string)$response->meta[0]->statuscode;
echo $statusCode;
```

Output

```
100
```